# Can I use somewhat between pronoun and verb?

Tags: word-usage

I want to know if my construction sounds natural. Here's my sentence:

> It's obvious that I will be failed since I
> **somewhat** don't have courage in the first place.

The reason I use somewhat is I want to say I have less courage. It doesn't mean I don't have it at all. This is the best word I could find although I still sense something odd about my sentence but I don't know which part.

Comment: Your sentence is not idiomatic. To fail, not to be failed. And since I don't have much courage in the first place.

Comment: No **somewhat** doesn't fit. You can't position **somewhat** in front of a verb. Think of it as **fairly**. It sounds somewhat ridiculous to say **I somewhat don't**.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thanks both of you. Is it still incorrect to use I don't somewhat? I thought  somewhat is roughly the same as "rather". No? What about this: I don't quite have courage.... Like when I say: I don't quite remember...